# Searching and getting the index for multi dimestional array in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

What is the best way to search for the index of object in multidimensional array. I tried to do it with **indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)**, but it seems that it takes two nested block like this. Is there any easier and efficient way to do this. Wandering if there is some efficient algorithm or the apple provided better method for this. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't think NSArray was designed to be nested in the first place.  I think you'll have to resort to using loops.

Comment: So what data structure is better for the nested types of list of objects.

Comment: It is because I am using NSArray to populate the tableview's rows and sections using multidimestional array. 
And now I want to retrieve a particular object from the array based on the search criteria.

Comment: Generally when I want to populate a Table View, I make a new object that encapsulates all of the data in that row instead of using multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer has the right approach, but it should be noted that NSArray can be nested just fine and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @sosborn There is nothing wrong with nested NSArray's.  The OP asked if there was any efficient algorithm or if Apple provided a method for easily navigating nested array's, which it doesn't afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's nothing utterly wrong with nesting arrays etc.!
Did you take a look at [Index Paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/IndexPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010167-SW1) (And [NSIndexPath class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexPath/indexAtPosition%3a))?

You probably still have to code a little bit to get things done, but the methods of NSIndexPath will help you!